# How to show the data set as per minute frequency based in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which have order details so for example if a 12345 order comes at 08-01-2018 00:02 and gets completes at 08-01-2018 00:06 so I want result set to be expand by minute to something like below. How can we do it SQL Server, basically want a separate row in the result for every minute from the start minute (00:02) to the end minute (00:06) please suggest, it should be generic and applicable to all other raw data.

Raw table:

```
OrderNo Order_received      Order_Completes
-------------------------------------------
12345   08-01-2018 00:02:00 08-01-2018 00:06:00
```

Desired result set

```
OrderNo. time                Order_received order_complete 
------------------------------------------------------------
12345    08-01-2018 00:02     1               0   
12345    08-01-2018 00:03     1               0   
12345    08-01-2018 00:04     1               0   
12345    08-01-2018 00:05     1               0   
12345    08-01-2018 00:06     0               1
```

Comment: what do you mean by *flash*?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Something like it should show the result set minute wise

Comment: changed my heading with more suitable description

Comment: How does the original data look before it's expanded to your desired results. Is this one input record with a `start` and `end` datetime, or two different records for the one order with a timestamp?

Comment: So, you want to show how many minutes it took before the order came in and thet time it was completed?

Comment: yes... I want result set as in my description

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a separate row in the result for every minute from the start minute (00:02) to the end minute (00:06), is that correct? If so, please add this as text into the question, so everybody will know what the question is about. Also, you need to show the source data (table structure + data row/rows), your question only contains the final desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will create a list of date/times:

```
Create Function [dbo].[DateTimeTbl](@BeginDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime)
RETURNS @retDate TABLE 
(
    Dt DateTime
)
BEGIN

    While @BeginDate <= @EndDate
    Begin

        Insert Into @retDate (Dt) Values (@BeginDate);
        Set @BeginDate = DateAdd("MINUTE", 1, @BeginDate);
    End


    RETURN;
END;
```

and usage:

```
SELECT * FROM DBO.[DateTimeTbl]('12/01/2015 12:01:00 AM', '12/01/2015 12:05:00 AM')
```

you can join this on your results

Comment: what if I have multiple records in my raw data then how to show the result for each record

Comment: you might need to create a procedure that loops through your records and calls the table function and adds the result to your tmp table

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive CTE, this also works for "open" orders with a null complete value:

```
DECLARE @myData TABLE (OrderNo INT, Order_Received DATETIME, Order_Completes DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @myData (OrderNo, Order_Received, Order_Completes)
VALUES (12345,'2018-01-08 00:02:00','2018-01-08 00:06:00')
       --, (55555,'2018-01-08 00:05:00',NULL)

;WITH AllMinutes (OrderNo, Order_Received, Order_Completes, [time]) AS
(
    SELECT OrderNo, Order_Received, Order_Completes,
           Order_Received AS [time]
    FROM @myData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT OrderNo, Order_Received, Order_Completes, 
           DATEADD(MINUTE,1,[time])
    FROM AllMinutes
    WHERE [time]<ISNULL(Order_Completes,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

)

SELECT OrderNo,
       [time],
       CASE WHEN [time] < ISNULL(Order_Completes,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN [time] = ISNULL(Order_Completes,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM AllMinutes
WHERE [time] <= ISNULL(Order_Completes,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY OrderNo, [time]
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use of recursive `CTE` method

```
;with cte as
(
    select OrderNo, order_completes, order_received  from table
    union all
    select OrderNo,order_completes, dateadd(minute,1,order_received) order_received 
    from cte
    where cte.order_received < order_completes
)
select c.OrderNo,
       c.order_received [Time],
       (case when c.order_received <> c.order_completes then 1 else 0 end) [Order_received],
       (case when c.order_received = c.order_completes then 1 else 0 end) [Order_received]    
from cte c
--option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
declare @iMinn datetime;
set @iMinn = (select top 1 time from [your_table] where 
              OrderNo. = 12345 order by time);
while @iMinn < (select top 1 time from [your_table] where OrderNo. = 
                12345 and order_complete = 1 order by time desc)  
begin
    select 
    OrderNo.,
    time,
    Order_received,
    order_complete
    from [your_table];
    set @iMinn = dateadd (minute,1,@iMinn);
end
```

Comment: Hi Lihi, I could not understand how to execute the same

Comment: I added a variable deff. you can copy and paste exectly as written, just replace [your_table} in your table name and range by the where you want to.

Comment: Hi Lihi, I am getting this error wgile executing  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'dateadd'.

Comment: This answer appears to assume that there is only one row in the table; it will not work as expected with multiple rows. Additionally, the `while` will either never loop (if order_complete = 1) or will loop infinitely (if order_complete = 0). __Edit__: The `dateadd` value needs to be assigned to @iMinn to correct the error that @user2503377 just described.

Comment: I suggested to range with where, but of course, it's not up to me. about the if - I assumed the value of order_completed is updated elsewhere

Comment: Not able to paste my code showing "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified" while pasting the code. I just replaced [your_table] with my table name

Comment: Can please show the range example with code please, how to give

Comment: look at my edited answer. I changed it assuming all the rows, including the 1 with order_complete =1, are already in the table. please let me know if it works.

Comment: Somehow I am getting same error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'dateadd'.. I am just copying and pasting your code and changing [your_table] with my table name that is mydata. I am using MSSQL 2012. Will this work for all the orderno as we have hard coded the same.

Comment: error showing at dateadd keyword                 "from [your_table];
    dateadd (minute,1,@iMinn);" in the code "Incorrect syntax near 'dateadd'."

Comment: I am so sorry! forgot to set the variable. lt should be - set @iMinn = dateadd (minute,1,@iMinn); sorry again! I also changed the answer. you can copy and paste again